# Plotting polygons onto folium with a gdf frame error

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, folium

I have an issue i made a fairly simple code I just create my file then create the map and the plot it but I get an error. I want to be plotting the polygons from the file onto the map.

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
import geopandas as gpd



input_map = "CLUSTERS.TAB"
gdf = gpd.read_file(input_map, driver="MapInfo File")


maploc = folium.Map(location=[42.377157,-71.236088],zoom_start=11,tiles="Stamen Toner")

folium.GeoJson(gdf).add_to(maploc)
```

The error I get is

```
builtins.RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

I have no idea what this means or how to fix it. Any input helps, Thanks.